# Read content when an Excel workbook is closed using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've two excel vba workbooks: 'Formini1.xlsm' as the source file; 'Tampil1.xlsm' as the target file.

The main fuction is: I've an advanced filter search in the target file. When I write a keyword and click the button this workbook, it searches in the source file and displays the related data in the target file.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RangeKriteria As Range, RangeCopyTo As Range, RangeTabel As Range

Set RangeTabel = Workbooks("formini1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").[A1].CurrentRegion
Set RangeCopyTo = Workbooks("tampil1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").[L1]
Set RangeKriteria = Workbooks("tampil1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").[A1:I10]
With Workbooks("tampil1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells.Clear
    .[A1:I1].Value = Workbooks("formini1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").[A1:I1].Value
    .[A2].Value = "*" & TextBox1.Value
    .[B3].Value = "*" & TextBox1.Value
    RangeTabel.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=RangeKriteria _
    , CopyToRange:=RangeCopyTo, _
        Unique:=False
End With    
End Sub
```

The problem is, in real implementation the source file ("formini1.xlsm")doesn't/mustn't always be opened. Is there any idea to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the source file if it's closed.  Add the following:

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim book As Workbook
    Dim filepath As String

    filepath = "C:\your_path\formini1.xlsm"

    'Open the workbook as read only to avoid access conflicts
    Set book = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath, ReadOnly:=True)



    ' Close the workbook after you have read the data
    book.Close
End Sub
```

I tested having the file already open, and for me, it did not fail.  If it does fail if already open, trap for the error and continue.